# How can I add header and footer XSLT files to another XSLT file to convert it into HTML?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am coding a `XSLT` program, which will convert `XML` to `HTML` format. I want to add header and footer to `XSLT`. It mean that I am thinking to add `header.xslt` and `footer.xslt` in my `content.xslt`.

Here is my code:
**XML file** `dataDetail.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="layout.xslt" type="text/xsl"?>
 <customerList>
    <customer id="101">
        <name>Jon</name>
        <email>Jon.sood@iqbsys.com</email>
        <age>23</age>
        <gender>male</gender>
    </customer>
</customerList>
```

Here is my main `xslt` file ie **layout.xslt**

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="content.xslt" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-imports />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my **content.xslt** file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Header content</h1>
                <h2>=======start content==========</h2>
                <h2>The customer details are: </h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="customerList/customer">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="email" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="gender" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>

                <h2>=======End content==========</h2>
                <h1>Footer content</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output of this is :**[image]

I want to display the content of Header and footer from two different `XSLT` files ie **footer.xslt** and **header.xslt**.

**How can I include these two xslt files to content.xslt ?** I have tried import but not getting the correct results.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I include these two xslt files to content.xslt ? I have tried import but not getting the correct results.

You have two main issues to tackle.

In the first place, you need the transformations defined in the separate header and footer stylesheets to be presented inside the main transformation.  You don't show any mechanism for doing that, but it's not hard: you need to insert `apply-templates` elements at the appropriate places in the main template.  It may be useful to use non-default modes for the header and footer templates.  For example,

**content.xslt**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>

                <!-- THIS: -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="header" />

                <h2>=======start content==========</h2>
                <h2>The customer details are: </h2>
                <!-- ... -->
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the second place, you need to incorporate the template(s) defined in your external files into the stylesheet defined in your main file.  This is what the XSL `import` and `include` elements are for, but since you're already using `import` I guess I don't need to go into detail.  Thus, it looks like this might fit into your scheme:

**layout.xslt**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="content.xslt" />
    <xsl:import href="header.xslt" />
    <xsl:import href="footer.xslt" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that no template is needed in this stylesheet; the imported stylesheets are being relied upon to provide all needed.  You might then write the header stylesheet like this, for example:

**header.xslt**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- note that this mode matches the one selected by the apply-templates
         in content.xslt: -->
    <xsl:template match="/" mode="header">
        <h1>Header Content</h1>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solution worked without any problem and is very clean and understandable. Thank you